# Fetching row id from SQLite database on clicking a listview item

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have populated listview from database using ArrayAdapter, i want to get the database-row id of the list item when i click the the item. I have searched many hours, but i couldn't get the answer because i am beginner.

here is my main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.quote_list);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        DatabaseAccess datac= DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        datac.open();
        final ArrayList<String> thelist = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data=datac.getquotes();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            thelist.add(data.getString(2));
           ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.textcenter,R.id.textitem,thelist);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } 
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_contextual_menu,menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `AdapterContextMenuInfo#id` field inside `onContextItemSelected` method - the docs say: *"The row id of the item for which the context menu is being displayed."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way,
1. When you click on the item of list view, you will get the id.
2. get the string value from that index and call a method where send collected string as a parameter and fire a query in that method like

```
return db.rawQuery("select row_id from your_tableName where string_columnName="+your_passed_string+";",null);
```

3. Collect row_id in your cursor and convert it into a int value then show it on screen.
4. Done.

Comment: your answer helped me to do it in different way. i retrived the list content using String selectqt= listAdapterf.getItem(info.position);   then i select the id from database using 'where' = selectqt.    thankyou